# Regex to find a keyword in complete string that may have spaces, new lines etc

Tags: regex

I want to make a regular expression that will find a keyword in complete string (string may have spaces, new lines etc.).

This is my regular expression for the keyword `email`

```
^([\n]*(.*))*[eE][^a-z]*[mM][^a-z]*[aA][^a-z]*[iI][^a-z]*[lL][^a-z]*([\n]*(.*))*$
```

It works well when there are less letters after `email` but not working when there are large characters (more than 10) after `email`.

Please correct this expression.

Comment: What about using modifiers like `/email/igm` ? - and is e2m2a2il is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your fixed regex:

```
^[\s\S]*[Ee][^a-z]*[Mm][^a-z]*[Aa][^a-z]*[Ii][^a-z]*[Ll][\s\S]*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hE1aA0/2)

Note that your regex caused [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) very soon, you can easily see that at regex101.com. The pattern `([\n]*(.*))*` that you used to match optional text before and after the keyword is very inefficient and it is to blame for the catastrophic backtracking.

To match any characters you can use `[\s\S]*` pattern that allows linear matching and is very efficient.

If you can use `i` ignorecase and `s` singleline modifiers, you can shorten the regex to

```
^.*e[^a-z]*m[^a-z]*a[^a-z]*i[^a-z]*l.*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hE1aA0/3)

And a hint: if `email` should be a whole word, you need to enclose it into word boundaries `\b` (so that it could not match `emailing`:

```
^.*\be[^a-z]*m[^a-z]*a[^a-z]*i[^a-z]*l\b.*$
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for such an outstanding explanation

Comment: Glad to help, please consider accepting the answer (a tick on the left right below the down arrow). Also, please consider upvoting (the up arrow) the answer if you found it helpful.